# Can't read from plist

Tags: iphone, plist

I have a plist with an array at top level and then a number of items within it.

When I try the following

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Spots.plist"];

spotsArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
```

the array spotsArray is empty.

I have tried a number of things and have used plists successfully before. I dont know what the issue is now.

What could be causing the issue, my plist looks like this [image: plist]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an array at the top level it's a dictionary with a single item called 'New Item'.

Try `NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] objectForKey:@"New Item"] mutableCopy] autorelease]`

Answer (score 0):

This should mean that your .plist file does not exist or not readable.
Try to create the file with writeToFile at the same path to verify it works. (It can also help you to verify the directory)

Comment: `[NSBundle mainBundle]` is not writeable on iOS devices